# How to change the order of a QCompleter popup?

Tags: c++, qt, qcompleter

I have created a custom `QCompleter` class which displays all items in a popup that contain the typed word of a `QLineEdit`.

Right now all items are ordered alphabetically as you can see here:

[image]

I want the popup to display "dab" as the first suggestion if I type in "dab" and then the other items in alphabetical order.

**I want this popup order:**

- dab
- amendable
- decidable
- dividable
- guidable
- spendable
- ...

## How can i achieve this?

This is the custom `QCompleter` class I'm using:

**Code**

```
class MyCompleter : public QCompleter
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    inline MyCompleter(const QStringList& words, QObject * parent) :
            QCompleter(parent), m_list(words), m_model()
    {
        setModel(&m_model);
    }

    // Filter
    inline void update(QString word)
    {
        // Include all items that contain "word".

        QStringList filtered = m_list.filter(word, caseSensitivity());
        m_model.setStringList(filtered);
        m_word = word;
        complete();
    }

    inline QString word()
    {
        return m_word;
    }

private:
    QStringList m_list;
    QStringListModel m_model;
    QString m_word;
};
```

Comment: Use proxy models. Or fill completer model by yourself, with desired order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it myself by creating a copy of my `m_list` and searching it with the `startsWith` function. I then added the found items to a `tempList` and filtered the `c_m_list` as I did in my question. The `filtered` list also got added to the `tempList`.

Now it looks like this:

[image: popup example]

**Code**

```
class MyCompleter : public QCompleter
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    inline MyCompleter(const QStringList& words, QObject * parent) :
            QCompleter(parent), m_list(words), m_model()
    {
        setModel(&m_model);
    }

    inline void update(QString word)
    {
        // Include all items that contain "word".
        int idx(0);
        QStringList tempList;
        QStringList c_m_list(m_list);

        while (idx < c_m_list.size())
        {
            if (c_m_list.at(idx).startsWith(word,Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                tempList.append(c_m_list.takeAt(idx--));
            }
            idx++;
        }

        QStringList filtered = c_m_list.filter(word, caseSensitivity());
        c_m_list.sort();

        tempList.append(filtered);

        m_model.setStringList(tempList);
        m_word = word;
        complete();
    }

    inline QString word()
    {
        return m_word;
    }

private:
    QStringList m_list;
    QStringListModel m_model;
    QString m_word;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

a faster update function:

```
inline void update(QString word)
{
    // Include all items that contain "word".
    QStringList filtered = m_list.filter(word, caseSensitivity());
    QStringList new_list;
    int index = 0;
    while (index < filtered.size()) {
        if (filtered.at(index).startsWith(word, Qt::CaseInsensitive)) {
            new_list.append(filtered.takeAt(index--));
        }
        ++index;
    }
    new_list.append(filtered);

    m_model.setStringList(new_list);
    m_word = word;
    complete();
}
```